# How to use pandas.to_datetime with "strange" strings formats

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, dataframe, machine-learning

I'm trying to convert a pandas dataframe's column from string type to datetime, using pandas.to_datetime.
The col's values have this format:

> Q1'17

where 'Q' is the quarter of the year and '17' is the year 2017.

I also have null's values in that column (I can remove the entire row where the date is empty).

I tried to solve it eliminating the quarter and considering only the year, but I could not convert, for example, 16 to 2016 in this way:

```
df_cpu["Launch_Date"] = [str(x) for x in df_cpu["Launch_Date"]]
df_cpu["Launch_Date"] = [x[3:5] for x in df_cpu["Launch_Date"]]
df_cpu["Launch_Date"] = [int(x) for x in df_cpu["Launch_Date"]]
df_cpu["Launch_Date"] = pd.to_datetime(df_cpu["Launch_Date"],    format('%Y'))
```

Even this way does not work:

```
df_cpu["Launch_Date"] = pd.to_datetime(df_cpu["Launch_Date"], format('Q*\'%Y'))
```

Because I obtain this error:

> ValueError: ('Unknown string format:', "Q3'16")

How should I solve this problem?

I'd like to have the following kind of output: if per example the value is "Q1'16" I'd like to have "01-01-2016".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering:

1) the data provided:

```
df_cpu = pd.DataFrame(["Q1'17","Q3'16"], columns=['Launch_Date'])
```

2) the launch date column will always have length 5;

You can use [pd.offsets.QuarterBegin()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.tseries.offsets.QuarterBegin.html#pandas.tseries.offsets.QuarterBegin) to add quarters to the first day of the year:

```
>> pd.to_datetime(df_cpu.Launch_Date.str[3:5],format='%y') + np.multiply(pd.offsets.QuarterBegin(startingMonth=1), df_cpu.Launch_Date.str[1:2].values.astype(int)-1)
0   2017-01-01
1   2016-07-01
Name: Launch_Date, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can `map` the first part of the string to a value that can be used in `to_datetime` after such as:

```
df_cpu = pd.DataFrame({'Launch_Date':["Q1'17", "Q3'16"]})
dict_Q = {"Q1": '01-01-', "Q3": '07-01-'}

print (pd.to_datetime( df_cpu["Launch_Date"].str[:2].map(dict_Q) #replace Qx by a first of month
                       + df_cpu["Launch_Date"].str[3:])) #get the year independtly

0   2017-01-01
1   2016-07-01
Name: Launch_Date, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

And don't forget to add Q2 and Q4 int `dict_Q` with the right value you want

Answer (score 2):

I'm no expert with datetime formatting conversions, but here's a solution that should work. I can't claim it's the most efficient though. I would write a function that returns the datetime in the format you prefer, the use the 'apply' method on the dataframe.

Note that the function below assumes the year is always 20--, and the output is a string. Change the output datatype as needed.

```
def new_date(arr):
    if isinstance(arr, str):
        quarter = {'Q1':'01-01-', 'Q2':'04-01-', 'Q3':'07-01-', 'Q4':'10-01-'}
        x, y = arr.split("'")[0], arr.split("'")[1]
        x_new = quarter[x]
        y_new = '20'+y
        return x_new + y_new
    else:
        pass

df_cpu["Launch_Date"] = df_cpu["Launch_Date"].apply(new_date)
```

Also note that the 'is_instance' conditional is only to handle NaN values. if you use pd.dropna(), it isn't required.